# Is it possible to specify charset for an element?

Tags: css, html

In html we can specify the charset for the whole document using:

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" /> 
</head>
```

But sometimes, it is impossible to change the charset of the whole page, for example , using injection.

I would like to declare the charset for a specified element,  like this

```
<span charset="utf-8">....</span>
```

but it seems it doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is impossible to do this.

It is also difficult to design a way for this to work even theoretically. Think about it: the browser already parses your syntax using the charset. Considering implicit tag closing rules in HTML making this work would be difficult indeed.

What you can do is include an IFrame with a completely different document using a different charset.

To understand this limitation even better the meta http-equiv elements are not even part of the HTML document architecturally. Rather they are another way to specify HTTP headers if you cannot do it in HTTP server configuration.